# `require': No such file to load -- test_helper (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, production-environment

I get the following error when I run my Rails application in production mode, but when I run my app in development mode it works fine.
Can I use any gems in production mode?

```
`require': No such file to load -- test_helper (LoadError)
```

The following is the full trace of the code:

```
 /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': No such file to load -- test_helper (LoadError)
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /home/nyros/Documents/Projects/DFL/Working/DFL/app/controllers/quarterly_export_statement_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:330:in `require_or_load'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:289:in `depend_on'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:207:in `require_dependency'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:347:in `eager_load!'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'  
from /home/nyros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /home/nyros/Documents/Projects/DFL/Working/DFL/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /home/nyros/Documents/Projects/DFL/Working/DFL/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /home/nyros/Documents/Projects/DFL/Working/DFL/config.ru:in `new'
from /home/nyros/Documents/Projects/DFL/Working/DFL/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
from /home/nyros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@dfl/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Share some more lines of stack trace

Comment: Why do you try to load a `test_helper` in the `production` environment? In what file to you get that error?

Comment: Are you trying to run tests in `production` environment? And post backtrace please

Comment: No, I'am not run any tests in production --@Vasfed

Comment: Put the full trace, please

Comment: I trust the problem is solved. But what did you mean by "Can I use any gems in production mode?"

Comment: Can you confirm in which directory you place test

Comment: I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 11):

You have a test, `quarterly_export_statement_test.rb`, in your `app/controllers` directory.

In production, Rails loads all classes eagerly, so it attempts to load your test. Your test does `require 'test_helper'`. The `test` directory, which contains `test_helper`, isn't in the load path in the production environment (good!), so that require fails.

To fix the problem, move the test to the `test` directory where it belongs, which appears to be `/home/nyros/Documents/Projects/DFL/Working/DFL/test`.

Comment: I was kind of gooled by the engines path part, but in the OP's case your answer, @dave, is correct. In general engines must not be below ./app, since, as you said, *all* files below app will be loaded eagerly in production.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while using: railstutorial.org Chapter 6.
The offending file for me was `app/helpers/application_helper_test.rb`
which had `require 'test_helper'` at the top.

I commented that line out, did

```
git add -A
git push
git push heroku
```

Then ran `heroku run console`, which worked :)

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with the same book and the same chapter6, you totally saved me brother! Thanks!
And I checked the author's github on main branch, that there is not application_helper_test.rb file in the helpers folder, and I am just so curious what cause the issue?
https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_6th_ed/tree/main/app/helpers