# Heroku app crashes every time I try to open

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to deploy my app using Heroku. I think I've successfully deployed it, but every time I try to open my app on the browser, it says...

> Application error An error occurred in the application and your page
>   could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs
>   for details

When I enter `heroku logs`, I get...

```
2017-07-15T14:20:37.334994+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-07-15T14:20:38.012558+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=deucex.herokuapp.com request_id=8a0d5560-e3bb-4cc2-82c3-9258db8eacb5 fwd="98.26.96.65" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I know my app crashes, but I don't know why. I tried entering `heroku restart`, doesn't work. I also tried looking up this problem, but without success. What should I do?

====== UPDATE =====

When I enter:

```
$ heroku run rake db:create
```

I get the following error:

```
FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"dd9p7e3qfv5v6k", "username"=>"dzkwulhdubxmkt", "password"=>"e3864a3452e40eb2586d5fc2f6052dd9e85e8fd59804151c4701ae046743e4a8", "port"=>5432, "host"=>"ec2-23-23-244-83.compute-1.amazonaws.com"}
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.20.0/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.20.0/lib/pg.rb:56:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.20.0/lib/pg.rb:56:in `connect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:701:in `connect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:220:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:38:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:38:in `postgresql_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:759:in `new_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:803:in `checkout_new_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:782:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:743:in `acquire_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:500:in `checkout'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:in `connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:931:in `retrieve_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:116:in `retrieve_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:88:in `connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:10:in `connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:19:in `create'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:117:in `create'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `block in create_current'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:304:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:303:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:303:in `each_current_configuration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:136:in `create_current'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:360:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/exe/bundle:35:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/exe/bundle:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

===== UPDATE ========

When I try to run:

```
$ rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
```

I get:

> ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError FATAL: database "sale_development" does
>   not exist

This is my database.yml code

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: sale_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: sale_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: sale_production
  username: sale
  password: <%= ENV['SALE_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Obviously `sale_development` DOES exist. Sale is the name of my app. Why is it saying it doesn't exist?

Gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
 "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
 end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

#gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"
gem 'devise', '~> 4.3'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'


# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development do
   # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'pg'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Comment: check if there's any environment variable that might be missing in the production environment, check if you ran your migrations

Comment: What would the command be for that?

Comment: you can find the environment variables on your heroku dashboard for the app in question, then `settings`->`reveal config vars`. To run the migrations you can open the console in heroku and run them or from your terminal, if you have the heroku toolbelt installed by running `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: Ok, so I'm under dashboards, where it says Personal Apps. To find the environment variables, should I click on my app from the dashboard?

Comment: Oh ok, I went to settings and clicked on reveal config vars. What should I be seeing there?

Comment: I also ran that migration

Comment: About the db:create, in heroku you can't create the DB, that's managed by heroku and will throw the error you experience. The config vars in heroku is where you set any environment variables you might have in your local environment, such as credentials for S3, email and others. Usually not being set won't by itself crash the app, but if some initialization code relies on having them set it might. Try accessing the app once again and then run `heroku logs` from your terminal.

Comment: Now when I try to open that app with rails server -b $IP -p $PORT it gives me the ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError
FATAL: database "sale_development" does not exist error

Comment: updated the question

Comment: What's your gemfile look like?

Comment: let me post it in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you create a database?
Try `heroku run rake db:create` or `heroku run rails db:create` and then migrate.

You get message sale_development doesn't exist because when you push to heroku it's starting your app in production  and for production, you have another db.

> Edited

When I look to heroku logs I find a `/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in require': No such file to load -- test_helper.rb (LoadError)` error.
[Here already fix same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129533/require-no-such-file-to-load-test-helper-loaderror)

Comment: Ok, how should I fix that?

Comment: For production, you must use: rails server -b $IP -p $PORT -e production

Comment: Also in your Gemfile you put pg 3 times, leave the first one

Comment: When I try that, I get error in the terminal Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:498:in `raise_no_secret_key': Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer: (RuntimeError)

  config.secret_key = 'bfdf50b1d72b1858a98533f33ef6765245853529ec48c39cc3920e58e05de871d970b2c198cb801ffba88bff268dceb38d8079f920f06e772c5792b44e9c6e42'

Please ensure you restarted your application after installing Devise or setting the key.
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.r...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149293/discussion-between-dendomenko-and-bockdavidson).